# Удаление элементов из массива C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Столкнулся с проблемой, не могу удалить два четных элемента массива, высвечивается ошибка и вызывается точно останова.Прошу помочь.Код:

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int size, rez, cheker;
    cout << "Input the size of the massive";
    cin >> size;
    int*a = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0;i <= size;i++) {
        a[size] = i;
        cheker = i % 2;
        if (cheker == 0) {
            cout << "The even numbers are\n" << a[size];
            int*b = new int[size-2];
            for (i = 0;i <= size;i += 2) {
                b[size] = i;
            }
            a = b;
            cout << "The deleted numbers are:" << b[size];
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А какая здесь подразумевается логика? Например, зачем нужен массив а, если обращение все время идёт к одному элементу a[size] - и более того, элемент с таким индексом не существует, что и вызывает ошибку.

Comment: `a[size]` - вылет за пределы массива. `b[size]` - вылет за пределы массива.

Comment: Что такое "удалить два четных элемента"? Четных по значению или по индексу? И если два, то какие два? Что делать, если их больше чем два?

Comment: Нужно удалить именно два значения из массива

Answer (score -4):

```
delete a[0];
delete a[2];
delete a[4];
```

и т.д. думаю ясно

если хотите только 2 удалить, то выбираете их так и удаляете

```
int i = 0, j = 2;//например, можно любые
delete a[i];
delete a[j];
```

Comment: Нет, не ясно. Что это?

Comment: удаление четных элментов массива а

Comment: Гениально. Но там же просили *два*.

Comment: а блин точно сейчас исправлю

Comment: Что за бред... delete применяется для совсем другой цели - освобожджения памяти - к указателям.